# Query custom post type with tags

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I created a custom post type named `portfolio`, and am trying to create a query to get similar posts from the `portfolio` post type based on if it has at least 1 similar tag.

For some reason this code displays tags from ANY post type, and if I remove the tags code, only posts from the `portfolio` type are displayed.

```
<div id="relatedbizposts">
    <h3 class="widgettitle">Related Businesses</h3>
    <ul id="relatedlist">
        <?php 
        $orig_post = $post;
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
        if ( $tags ) {
            $tag_ids = array();
            foreach ( $tags as $individual_tag ) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
            $args = array(
                'post_type'        => 'portfolio',
                'tag__in'          => $tag_ids,
                'post__not_in'     => array( $post->ID ),
                'posts_per_page'   => 8, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
                'caller_get_posts' => 1
            );
            $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
            if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="relatedthumb">
                            <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('small'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <? }
            }
        }
        $post = $orig_post;
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `tag__and` instead of `tag__in`.

Comment: Could you print_r your tag_ids array?

Comment: Sounds like `tax_query` could come in useful here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [wp_get_post_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

Example usage: 
$term_lists = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_tag', array("fields" => "names"));

I modified your code and got this to work on my site:

```
<ul id="relatedlist">
        <?php 

        $tags = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_tag');
        if ( $tags ) {
            $tag_ids = array();
            foreach ( $tags as $individual_tag ) array_push($tag_ids,$individual_tag->term_id);

            $args = array(
                'post_type'        => 'product',
                'tax_query' => array( 
                                array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 
                                        'field' => 'id',
                                        'terms' => $tag_ids
                                      )
                                    ),
                'post__not_in'     => array( $post_id ),
                'posts_per_page'   => 8, // Number of related posts that will be shown.

            );
            $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="relatedthumb">
                        x
                            <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('small'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <? }
            }
        }

        wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
```

note: caller_get_posts is deprecated since version 3.1